# What is the python equivalent of R's package::function?

Tags: python, r, package, python-import, python-module

In R I can use a function in two different ways. First is to load the library and then use the function.

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- select(df, column)
```

Or I name the package when I call the function without loading the package first (it should be installed though). This saves space in the script when I use only one function from a certain package. It also helps with reading the code.

```
df2 <- dplyr::select(df, column)
```

In python I do this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

Is there a way to only write:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(df)
```

without the import statement?

Comment: why would you do this? in python you can do `__import__("pandas").DataFrame()` but what is the use case? it's literally just one line longer

Comment: What's wrong with importing? That's how you tell Python to bring the package into scope.

Comment: If you only need the specific function you could do `from pandas import DataFrame`. Note that the `::` is a scope resolution operator. It does not mean that you only import that particular function but rather it allows you to not fall in tthe trap of ambiguity for example `dplyr` contains `filter` function while `stats` contains `filter` function also. To distinguish the two filter functions you use the scope resolution operator ie `stats::filter` vs `dplyr::filter`. Note that in python unless you import the individual items from the module, this problem wont exist.

Comment: ah ok, I guess they are just two different languages that work differently